# Bootstrap in Internet Explorer on a Tablet

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just have a general question about IE and tablets.

I'm redesigning this website and incorporating Bootstrap into it. Currently, I'm working on the IE browser on the small size (tablet) and was wondering if there are any tablets out there that actually use Internet Explorer as their browser?

My concern is I don't want to spend the time trying to get the CSS right for the small size for IE if no one will be using IE at the tablet size.

I tried researching which tablets use IE but I found no good leads.

Any answers or ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure windows phones and tablets are the only devices that have internet explorer as their default browser and the only devices where you can install it.
They only represent around 3% of the smartphone and tablet market share.

Are you writing unique css just for IE browsers? Bootstrap is made to support all modern browsers. You shouldn't be having major issues with different browsers.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. Bootstrap works just fine in IE 9, 10, 11(Edge?) but my company still supports IE 8 and IE7 so  that's where I am trying to determine if its even worth the time and effort.

Comment: According to the bootstrap docs. They do support IE8 and IE9. Unofficially, it should also display fine in IE7, but they don't support it. http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/getting-started/

Comment: But yeah, with IE7 and IE8 you'll probably run into a few issues.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I have encorporated HTMLSHIV and Respond.js so it helps alot in IE7. I cant wait till IE7 is dead lol. I guess I wont even bother, as long as the functionality is there, we are all good.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: :) I wouldn't worry too much about it either. Also, IE8 was released on 2009 and Windows Phone OS was released on 2010. So I'm guessing they had a more updated version of IE by then.